# Localization in Spring with Freemarker

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I am having issues with while working on Localization using Spring+ Freemarker. When I set the browser language as es(Spanish), it works fine. But, when I leave the browser language as default (en-US), it does not load the Spanish text. In fact it loads English texts.

We are controlling localization based on language flag on server side (as of now, may not be the correct way but it's like that for now).

My **FreeMarkerConfigurer** is set up as

```
@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfigurer() throws ParseException {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/freemarker/");
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    //Hardcoded locale just to test Spanish by default
    properties.put("locale", "es");
    configurer.setFreemarkerSettings(properties);
    Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    variables.put("utils", new FreemarkerUtils());
    configurer.setFreemarkerVariables(variables);
    return configurer;
}
```

I have two templates with name **test.ftl** and **test_es.ftl**. So, what I was thinking is it should pick up **test_es.ftl** by default. It picks up if I change the browser preference language to **es** but it does not by default. I also tried setting up **properties.put("localized_lookup", "false");** but did not work.